# Null results for a specific column - php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My query returns the correct data when executed on the db, but when run live the company_title comes back null. All other fields work.
$row['company_name']   is the code i can't get to work:

```
$query = "select * from invoices i, company_lookup cl, students s where i.company_id = cl.company_id and i.student_id = s.student_id;";

$results = $DB->query($query);

$invoices = mysql_query("select * from invoices");

?>
<table border="1" id="hl" name="hl">
    <tr>
    <th>Month/Year</th>
    <th>Full Amount</th>
    <th>Company</th>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($invoices)) { 
    $invoice_date = $row['invoice_date'];
    ?>
    <tr onMouseOver="showInvoicePayments(<? echo $row['invoice_id'] ?>);this.bgColor = '#C0C0C0'" onMouseOut ="this.bgColor = '#FFFFFF'" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
        <td><? echo  date('F Y',strtotime($invoice_date)) ?></td>
        <td><? echo '$' . $row['full_amount'] ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row['company_name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure, databases on live and on your dev machine are identical?

Comment: Is there actually a company_name field in any of the tables you're using? Just because you can use any key you want in a PHP array reference (your $row), doesn't mean there's actually a corresponding field result from MySQL.

Comment: @ini because you're getting rows of `$invoices` not `$query ` try `$results['company_name']`

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code, because of the '*', but is company_name in the $results resource, not the $invoices resource. ie the company_name is not in the $row array, because you are iterating the wrong result $invoices not $results.

Comment: closer! using $results  returns a company name, but it's not differentiating between different names.   The company_id is either 1 or 2, with different company_names, and the records that have company 2 are showing up as company 1. Any ideas? The company names show up correctly when I run the query in myPHPadmin

Answer (score 1):

try adding `COALESCE` in some of your fields.

like this one:

```
SELECT ..., COALESCE(company_title, ''),
            COALESCE(company_name, '')
        ...
```

Instead of `null` value, it will return an *empty string*.